# How to programmatically determine if the iPhone's passcode was changed or removed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm working on an app where I need to find out if the user has changed iPhone's passcode from Settings. 
Please note that I know "How to determine if the iPhone has passcode enabled". 
What I want to know is if the user has changed the passcode or not!

Comment: ask your question clearly, once you are edited the question after that you mention in comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, it's not possible to **observe** passcode changes using any public iOS APIs.

The only thing you can do is check if the passcode (or biometric authentication method: TouchID, FaceID) is enabled or disabled using LocalAuthentication framework APIs.